# Is it necessary to define the array before appending to it?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, append, isset

Trivial question.

Suppose I have the following code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$words = ['Apple', 'Avocado', 'Banana', 'Blueberry'];

$dict = [];
// build a dictionary keyed on the first letter
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $letter = $word[0];
    // is this condition necessary?
    if (!isset($dict[$letter])) {
        $dict[$letter] = [];
    }
    $dict[$letter][] = $word;
}
?>
```

Usually when I build a dictionary, before appending an entry, I ensure that the array exist as shown in my example.

I always thought a warning would show up otherwise, however it does not seem to be the case.

So is the IF condition necessary?

Comment: Well if it's already set it would get overwritten, but other than that it's not necessary.

Comment: `If` is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (emphasis mine):

> `$arr[key] = value;`
>
> `$arr[] = value;`
>
> `// key may be an integer or string`
>
> `// value may be any value of any type`
>
> If `$arr` doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an
>   alternative way to create an array. This practice is however
>   discouraged because if `$arr` already contains some value (e.g. string
>   from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and `[]`
>   may actually stand for string access operator. **It is always better to
>   initialize a variable by a direct assignment.**

No warning will be produced, but for clarity's sake it is preferred to initialize by direct assignment as you've always been doing.

Comment: Interesting. So many years with PHP yet I never knew this little gem.